# Assign methods to object by iterating over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

In ES5, I know that it's possible to assign methods to an object using a `forEach` loop in the following way:

```
var myMethods = [
  {
    name: 'start',
    src: someFn
  },
  {
    name: 'stop',
    src: someOtherFn
  }
];

var myObject = {};

myMethods.forEach(function(method) {
  myObject[method.name] = method.src;
});
```

In ES2015 (or ES6), is it possible to define these methods in tandem with creating the object? Here is an example of how I might expect this to work:

```
// example
const myObject = {
  [...myMethods.map((method) => method.name)]: [...myMethods.map(method) => method.src)]
}
```

The end result would look like this:

```
const myObject = {
  start: someFn,
  stop: someOtherFn
}
```

If there *is* a way to iterate over these methods and assign them to `myObject`, I would happily restructure the `myMethods` array so that this is possible.

The end goal is to be able to assign each of these methods in an external module and not have to duplicate the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Object.assign` and the spread operator in conjunction with computed property names to do

```
var myObject = Object.assign({}, ...myMethods.map(({name, src}) => ({[name]: src})));
```

First we map `myMethods` to an array of little one-property objects, whose key is given by the value of the `name` property and value by the `src` property. Then we use the spread operator `...` to pass these to `Object.assign` as parameters. `Object.assign` then glues them all together for us.

Comment: A+ Nice one-liner and detailed explanation

Comment: Never use this code in production. That's great that it can be done in few symbols, but it wastes a lot of computer time to create unnecessary objects: http://jsperf.com/assign-vs-reduce/4 Reduce is probably better for that case

Answer (score 3):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) should do the trick for you. Note that the optional second parameter is used to start with an empty object at the beginning.

```js
var myMethods = [{
  name: 'start',
  src: function() {
    console.log('started')
  }
}, {
  name: 'stop',
  src: function() {
    console.log('stopped')
  }
}];

var myObject = myMethods.reduce((obj, method) => {
  obj[method.name] = method.src;
  return obj;
}, {})


console.log(myObject)
myObject.start()
myObject.stop()
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm going to go ahead and assume that using `reduce` is new to OP, otherwise he'd already have been using it over that `forEach` solution

Comment: You can also use `Object.assign`. e.g. `myMethods.reduce((obj, method) => Object.assign(obj, {[method.name]: method.src}), {});` so you get some ES6 goodness.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to `myObject` at same line of `myMethods` assignnemts

```
var myObject = {};

someFn = function(){console.log(this)};
someOtherFn = function(){console.log(this)};

var myObject = {};

someFn = function(){};
someOtherFn = function(){}

var myMethods = [
  {
    name: (myObject["start"] = "start"),
    src: (myObject["start"] = someFn)
  },
  {
    name: (myObject["stop"] = "stop"),
    src: (myObject["stop"] = someOtherFn)
  }
];
```